# c++ ifstream file is open but fails

Tags: c++, ifstream

im trying to parse a file. however, the ifstream object keeps failing. in my parsing header file i have this:

```
class ParseDFA {
public:
  bool stop_program = false;
  std::ifstream dfa_file;
  ParseDFA(std::string parse_filename);
};
```

in my parsing cpp file i have this:

```
ParseDFA::ParseDFA(std::string parse_filename) {
  dfa_file.open(parse_filename, std::ifstream::in);

  if (dfa_file.fail()) {
    stop_program = true;
  }
}
```

and in my main.cpp file i have this:

```
std::string filename = "no000.dfa";
ParseDFA *dfa_file = new ParseDFA(filename);
if (dfa_file->stop_program) {
  std::cout << "Error opening file." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

my output:

```
Error opening file.
```

I know the file is open because in my parsing cpp file, i changed dfa_file.fail() to !dfa_file.is_open() and it stopped giving me that error. so what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I was able to fix the problem by putting the file's full path in variable filename. so like in my main.cpp file i have

```
std::string filename = "/Users/myname/Documents/DFA/no000.dfa";
```

Comment: stop_program is undefined.

Comment: @n.m. it actually is defined i just forgot to write it down on here. sorry!

Comment: @astrocat1997: Can you expand your example so it can be used to reliably *reproduce* the behaviour you observed, both the `fail()` and the `! is_open()`?

Comment: @DevSolar what more do you need? sorry im new to c++ so im not sure what else i should put.

Comment: Write a minimum and complete C++ code that reproduces the issue and can be compiled. Your code is incomplete.

Comment: Right now I can take the code you posted, add a bit of boilerplate, and get a `fail()` / `! is_open()` if the file does not exist, and `! fail()` / `is_open()` if it *does* exist. Apparently you have a case where you get `fail()` AND `is_open()`, a condition I am unable to reproduce. Can you write a complete program that shows anybody the same thing you are describing?

Answer (score 4):

Initialize `stop_program` in the constructor.

Comment: sorry! i had it initialized but i just forgot to write it on here. it should be good now.